# Why does validation not prevent submitting of the form for second input field?

Tags: jquery, validation

I have a form that when submitted with generate output on different portion of the page.  All client side.  I want to validate the form before I try to generate output:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jzaefferer.github.com/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $( "#processForm" ).validate({
                submitHandler: function(form) {
                    $( "#output" ).empty().append( $("#numberOne").val() );
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <form id="processForm">
        <p><input type="text" id="numberOne" value="37" class="required number"/></p>
        <p><input type="text" id="numberTwo" value="63" class="required number"/></p>
        <!--<p><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></p>-->
        <p><button type="submit">Submit</button></p>
    </form>
    <div id="output"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The validation of `numberOne` works fine and prevents my code from being executed, but for `numberTwo` it appears to allow `submitHandler` to still run.  Steps to reproduce:

1. Open, press submit, notice 37 is printed below submit button
2. Enter "asdf" in first field, press submit button, notice 37 remains below submit button
3. Enter "5" in first field, "asdf" in second field, press submit button.  "5" will show up below "submit" button, even though the form is not valid as a whole.

The error message does show up, but gets cleared when "submit" is pressed.  What am I missing?

I tried both `input` and `button` tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a name attribute on the inputs.  Generally, you want to add the name attribute if you are processing or sending data. Therefore, your inputs will look like this:

```
<input type="text" id="numberOne" name="numberOne" value="37" class="required number"/>
<input type="text" id="numberTwo" name="numberTwo" value="63" class="required number"/>
```

I have created a fiddle so you can confirm this is the functionality you are looking for.

http://jsfiddle.net/tokersey/FyjWs/

Comment: That worked, thank you.  Looking at the source code of the validator (not sure exactly how it works), they do use name's for identifiers, thus empty empty names would explain why the rules applied only to first field.